# How to make an OR selector instead of an AND statment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This statement will look for the div `#content-company` and load the appropriate data when it finds it. However my problem is:

On this occasion I have to use a slider that I can't rename to the same as the div so in this instance I have an additional called .slides

I normally would do this:

```
// JavaScript Document
  $(function(){
    $('.tileSB').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
        $('#content-company, .slides').load(url);
    });
});
```

But that simply overlays both the content associated with the div and the slides class so you have them with the same name at the same time and I don't want that.

Can someone explain how I can have this?:

```
// JavaScript Document
  $(function(){
    $('.tileSB').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
        $('#content-company OR .slides').load(url);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('#content-company, .slides').first().load(url);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the `#content-company` element exists. If it doesn't you can use `.slides` instead. Something like this:

```
$('.tileSB').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
    var $target = $('#content-company');
    if (!$target.length)
        $target = $('.slides');
    $target.load(url);
});
```

Comment: for some reason the click doesn't seem to load the content again from .slides really odd

Comment: WHEN REFERRING TO DATA-TARGET AND it is a ul class do i have to do something different other than the usual .slides ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `? :`(ternary operator). The code below will use the `#content-company`, if it existst otherwise uses `.slides`.

```
var $selector = $('#content-company').length ? $('#content-company') : $('.slides');
$selector.load(url);
```

Comment: In your code `$selector = $('#content-company') || $('.slides')`, the `$('.slides')` will never get executed

Comment: @ArunPJohny What about now, please check updated answer

Comment: In your update `$selector` could possibly be an int value, calling `.load()` on that would cause an error.

Comment: This still won't work, since you'll get the value `1` as `$selector`.

Comment: it could through an error saying load is not method

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this:

```
$("#content-company, .slides").first()
```

**Note that *first* element is determined according to HTML order**. If more than one matching elements are found then the first one in HTML order is returned.